# IndexError: pop index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written this code:

```
filename=input("Give the name of a file,for example example.txt\n")
file = open(filename, "r+") 
text = file.read()
frequency = []
alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
for letter in alphabet:
    frequency.append(text.count(letter))
for i in range(13):
    maximum = max(frequency)
    minimum = min(frequency)
    maxpos = frequency.index(maximum)
    minpos = frequency.index(minimum)
    text = text.replace (str(maximum), str(minimum))
    text = text.replace (str(minimum), str(maximum))
    alphabet.pop(maxpos)
    alphabet.pop(minpos)
    frequency.pop(maxpos)
    frequency.pop(minpos)
file.close()
```

This code is supposed to read a text from a file,then replace the most common letter with the least common letter and vice versa,then replace the second most common letter with the second least common letter and so on.
However,I get this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.py", line 16, in <module>
    alphabet.pop(minpos)
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After you `pop` the `maxpos`, the index of the `minpos` may have shifted

Comment: Also, if you first replace all `maximum` with `minimum`, and then the other way around, you end up wit all being `maximum`.

Comment: It is a bad idea to perform pop while iteration. You could just filter or as @tobias_k has said recompute `maximum` and `minimum` at each step because they will tend to shift if you `pop` an element.  Why can't you use `dict` here?

Comment: You can also "mark" the letters to replace with a special character. Something like that perhaps `text = text.replace(str(maximum), "$")` and `text = text.replace(str(minimum), "£")` then only replace() the `$` and `£` in your text. This will avoid the issue mentioned by @tobias_k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems with your code:

- after `pop(maxpos)`, `minpos` may not point to the right character any more if `minpos > maxpos`; in particular, this could even result in the index error if `minpos` is (was) the last position in the string
- if your first `replace(maximum, minimum)`, and then `replace(minimum, maximum)`, all of *both* `maximum` *and* `minimum` will end up as `maximum`

Instead, I'd suggest using `collections.Counter` and `str.translate`:

```
import collections, string
text = """This code is supposed to read a text from a file,then replace the most common letter with the least common letter and vice versa,then replace the second most common letter with the second least common letter and so on. However,I get this problem:""".lower()

counts = collections.Counter(text)
srtd = ''.join(sorted(set(text).intersection(string.ascii_lowercase), key=counts.get))
# 'xbugfvwpdilcarhnmsote'
result = text.translate(str.maketrans(srtd, srtd[::-1]))
# 'bwcg iuax cg gorrugxa bu pxda d bxeb mpuf d mclx,bwxv pxrldix bwx fugb iuffuv lxbbxp hcbw bwx lxdgb iuffuv lxbbxp dva ncix nxpgd,bwxv pxrldix bwx gxiuva fugb iuffuv lxbbxp hcbw bwx gxiuva lxdgb iuffuv lxbbxp dva gu uv. wuhxnxp,c sxb bwcg rputlxf:'
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work.I got no errors,but the script did nothing when I ran it. My code:`import collections, string
filename=input("Give the name of a file,for example example.txt\n")
file = open(filename, "r+") 
text = file.read()
counts = collections.Counter(text)
srtd = ''.join(sorted(set(text).intersection(string.ascii_lowercase), key=counts.get))
text.translate(str.maketrans(srtd, srtd[::-1]))
file.close()`

Comment: @Antonis I originally ran this in the interactive shell which automatically echos all results. Like `replace`, `translate` is not in-place, so you have to add `result = ...` (fixed)

Comment: It still did nothing...I don't know why